# Change stock status names in WooCommerce variable products selector?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I have this code:

```
$stock_status = $variation_obj->get_stock_status();
$stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
if( $stock_qty>0 )
    return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status . ' ('.$stock_qty.')';
else
    return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status;

}
```

I use it to show the variation stock status like "In Stock" or "Out of Stock". Currently this part of my function works, but show the stock status is this way:

[image]

So I want to ask someone how to show "In Stock" instead of "instock" as is shown in image under. 
I tryed to use some functions for custom stock status, but looks like dont have any effect.

Any help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) PHP function this way:

```
$stock_status = $variation_obj->get_stock_status();

// Here we change both $stock_status names to human readable strings:
$stock_status = str_replace( array('instock','outofstock'), array('In Stock','Out of Stock'), $stock_status );

$stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();

if( $stock_qty>0 )
    return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status . ' ('.$stock_qty.')';
else
    return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status;

}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Working perfect !