# WooCommerce customizing Variation Dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to customize woocommerce variations dropdown, Like if we have 2 variations **color** and **size**, with one color the size "Large" is out of stock, is it possible to add "out of stock" with each variation dropdowns.

Comment: yes, I have custmozed but I am failed to get available quantity so i can choose options for out of stock. 

Thanks

Comment: This is possible only when you have 1 drop down, but with more than one, this is not possible and not logical… I have answer a question like this one but with one dropdown only. With more than one it can't work.

Comment: This is the answer I have maid around this problem: [Change stock status names in WooCommerce variable products selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190106/change-stock-status-names-in-woocommerce-variable-products-selector/45191198#45191198) and this one too: [Show stock status next to each attribute value in WooCommerce variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037405/show-stock-status-next-to-each-attribute-value-in-woocommerce-variable-products/45041602#45041602) … So this is what can be done…

Comment: Thanks, but actually I am trying to do like this if this make sense.
https://loonoutdoors.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/outofstock.pdf

Comment: can you please provide me some help

Comment: Sorry, this is too broad, very complicated and a real development… I have already a lot of work to achieve for real clients…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your theme/functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'customizing_variations_terms_name', 10, 1 );
function customizing_variations_terms_name( $term_name ){

if(is_admin())
    return $term_name;

global $product;
$second_loop_stoped = false;

// Get available product variations
$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

// Iterating through each available product variation
foreach($product_variations as $variation){

    $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
    $variation_obj = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

    ## WOOCOMMERCE RETRO COMPATIBILITY ##
    if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) # BEFORE Version 3 (older)
    {
        $stock_status = $variation_obj->stock_status;
        $stock_qty = intval($variation_obj->stock);

        // The attributes WC slug key and slug value for this variation
        $attributes_arr = $variation_obj->get_variation_attributes();
    }
    else # For newest verions: 3.0+ (and Up)
    {
        $stock_status = $variation_obj->get_stock_status();
        $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();

        // The attributes taxonomy key and slug value for this variation
        $attributes_arr = $variation_obj->get_attributes();
    }

    if(count($attributes_arr) != 1) // Works only for 1 attribute set in the product
        return $term_name;

    // Get the terms for this attribute
    foreach( $attributes_arr as $attr_key => $term_slug){
        // Get the attribute taxonomy
        $term_key = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attr_key );

        // get the corresponding term object
        $term_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $term_key );
        if( $term_obj->name == $term_name ){ // If the term name matches we stop the loops
            $second_loop_stoped = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($second_loop_stoped)
        break;
}
if( $stock_qty>0 )
    return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status . ' ('.$stock_qty.')';
else
    return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status;

}
```

Posted here thanks to [loictheaztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) :

[Show stock status next to each attribute value in WooCommerce variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037405/show-stock-status-next-to-each-attribute-value-in-woocommerce-variable-products)